# How do I stretch the view when tab is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitabcontroller

I'm using the auto layout via the storyboard.

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    //hide bottom bar
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true


}

// postload func
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false

}
```

[image]

As you can see black is tabczontroller's height..How do I stretch the view to screen's bottom?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just layout to bottom layout guide which contains the tab bar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had solved to check "Hide bottom Bar on Push" instead of self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true thanks :)